# I silence birds

Tags: riddle

Note: I wrote this one a short while back but never actually posted it as a question, fairly straightforward and easy, have fun :) (Obviously it's a 'what am I? classic riddle')

*I silence birds and stop mills,

Hide hills and make rivers still.

Meanwhile, I'll make beasts slumber,

I cannot stay, but I may linger.*

Comment: Spoilerz guys. Come on :(

Comment: I shall return soon :O

Comment: You aren't *lingering* about?     (dum dum dummmmmmmm)

Comment: What’s up with the capitalization of Mills?

Comment: Fixed; Not too sure why I had put it capitalized , just one of *those* moments, ...you know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> Winter

I silence birds and stop Mills,

> Since birds mate in the spring, they don't sing until winter ends. Mills shut down in winter because there is no grain to grind, since it was all harvested in the summer/fall. Furthermore, if the mill is hydro powered, the river may freeze over and not be able to power the mill.

Hide hills and make rivers still.

> Heavy snowfall can make hills seem flat (if the area around the hill is covered with more snow), and rivers can freeze over, giving them the illusion of being still.

Meanwhile, I'll make beasts slumber,

> Animals hibernate in wintertime: examples include bears, squirrels, and skunks.

I cannot stay, but I may linger.

> Summer will always roll around (Even when Winter Is Coming), but winter will last a while. Added by jpmc26: the word linger could also be a reference to times when it seems to last longer than other winters (i.e. Groundhog Day).

Comment: Ninja'd! Nicely done.

Comment: Dang, and I thought I was typing fast :P

Comment: Haha, thanks! I happened to be the third person to view the riddle; just got lucky. It took me a little to figure it out. At first I thought of canary in the coal mines. I had to think for 3 minutes before I came up with an answer. :P

Comment: I think we had 3 answers in 4 minutes. 4 if you count dennis's deleted one.

Comment: This is the intended answer. It is also a better answer than snow though I do understand the ambiguity 'Hiding hills' causes. - also you were first :P

Comment: I think the "may linger" is probably a reference to the fact that sometimes it seems to last longer than other times. (Groundhog's Day comes to mind.)

Answer (score 6):

You are:

> Snow

I silence birds and stop Mills,

> Birds tend to not sing as much during the winter (or they fly south, so we don't hear them), and mills cannot run if there is no running water to power them.

Hide hills and make rivers still.

> Snow covers hills, and freezes rivers.

Meanwhile, I'll make beasts slumber,

> Most animals hibernate during the winter and snow.

I cannot stay, but I may linger.

> Snow eventually melts, but sometimes it hangs around for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Snow

I silence birds and stop Mills,

> Birds fly south for the Winter when it becomes too cold. Usually when there is snow you won't hear birds. Mills (old fashioned ones) don't operate during cold temperatures as there is no grain to grind and they are powered by wind/water.

Hide hills and make rivers still.

> Hills are covered in snow and rivers are frozen over

Meanwhile, I'll make beasts slumber,

> Animals (mammals) hibernate during the winter

I cannot stay, but I may linger.

> Snow will usually stay after Winter ends (especially in Canada) into Spring

Answer (score 3):

I made this fit because the title made me do it.

> Gas

I silence birds and stop Mills:

> When the canary kicks the bucket, the miners leave and the mills shut down from lack of materials.

Hide hills and make rivers still:

> Gases can obscure your vision and through a phase change they can (still) make rivers.

Meanwhile, I'll make beasts slumber:

> While high enough concentrations will kill the canary, larger beasts may simply lose consciousness. Also, you know... laughing gas.

I cannot stay, but I may linger.

> Wind can blow them away but gasses that are heavier than air will linger in depressions.